# Send a picture using cordova on android

Tags: android, image, cordova

I am having problems with Apache Cordova and Android. I have some code to send one picture to server, from an Android cellphone, but it doesn't work.  I have tested the ajax and php code on the server, and it works, but when I try from the cellphone it does not.

app.js:

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
var image = "";


document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
    });
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage'); 
    smallImage.style.display = 'block';     
    smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function submitFunction() { 
    var dataString = 'image='+encodeURIComponent(image);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "//192.0.1.2/testing/test.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        error: function(){
            ShowStatus( "AJAX - error()" );
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Error';
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 'Enviando Data';
        },
        success: function(result){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
        }
    });
}
```

test.php:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    require'connection.php';

    $mysqli = conectarse();
    $res = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO imagenes (image) VALUES
        ('".$_POST['image']."')");

    $mysqli->query($res);

    if (!$res) {
        printf("Errormessage: %sn", $mysqli->error);
    }
?>
```

This code has the following dependencies:

- cordova.js
- jquery.min.js

Comment: please include all the relevant code in the question itself

Comment: Can you get the error logcat or if possible chrome dev tools? My guess is you can't hit this address: `//192.0.1.2/testing/test.php`